# JavaScript Subtraction weird behavior

Tags: javascript

HI i am seeing a weird behavior of "-"  operator in javaScript for the following equation

```
 currVal = currVal-1;
```

here for the value of `currVal` =2.3 the equation is giving result as 1.2999999999999998 & similarly for 1.4 its giving 0.3999999999999999

Comment: @demongolem is right. That question has the answer to your question. You should use `number.toFixed(x)`, where x is the desired amount of decimal points.

Comment: Ya he is right but i was doing a decrement operation which needs to show the exact figures if possible so toFixed() i am considering as a last option . How ever i saw currVal = currVal+1; does not give any problem